# Must declare the scalar variable "@ in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure as shown below. When i use the command so as to call the stored procedure, i get the error message

> Must declare the scalar variable "@MusNo"."

I would like to ask your help.

```
exec sp_executesql N' execute [isb].[SP_GetNakitIslemSorguList_Test] NULL,159986569,''2016/01/01 12:23:45'',''2016/03/03 21:10:12'' '

USE [ATMDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE proc [isb].[SP_GetNakitIslemSorguList_Test]
(
 @IslemKodu as varchar(30),
 @MusNo as bigint,
 @StartDate as Date,
 @EndDate as Date
)
AS
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AddToWhereSql varchar(50)
IF @IslemKodu is null
BEGIN
 SET @AddToWhereSql = '1=1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SET @AddToWhereSql = 'IslemKodu = @IslemKodu'  
END
BEGIN
SET @Sql = N'SELECT [KartNo],[HesapNo],[TCKN],[CepTel],[MusNo],[Alacakli],[Tutar],[Tarih],[AtmNo],[Borclu]
    FROM [ATMDB].[isb].[NakitIslemSorgu] WITH (NOLOCK)       
    WHERE MusNo = @MusNo  and cast([Tarih] as Date)>= @StartDate and cast([Tarih] as Date) <= @EndDate and CashResult = 0
    and ' +   @AddToWhereSql + ' ORDER BY Tarih DESC'
exec sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO
```

Comment: Change `WHERE MusNo = @MusNo  and` to `WHERE MusNo = ' + @MusNo + ' and`

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for choosing to use dynamic SQL versus simply having the condition (`and (IslemKodu = @IslemKodu or @IslemKodu is null`) in the where clause? Also, you should rename your stored proc because the `sp_` prefix is reserved by MS for their *system* procedures.

Answer (score 2):

As you pass in a Variable @MusNo of type `BIGINT` you must concatenate its value into your dynamic SQL. Try it like this:

```
SET @Sql = N'SELECT [KartNo],[HesapNo],[TCKN],[CepTel],[MusNo],[Alacakli],[Tutar],[Tarih],[AtmNo],[Borclu]
    FROM [ATMDB].[isb].[NakitIslemSorgu] WITH (NOLOCK)       
    WHERE MusNo = ' + CAST(@MusNo AS VARCHAR(100)) + '  and cast([Tarih] as Date)>= @StartDate and cast([Tarih] as Date) <= @EndDate and CashResult = 0
    and ' +   @AddToWhereSql + ' ORDER BY Tarih DESC'
```

Answer (score 1):

sp_executesql requires the variables to be declared and initialised. This is done using parameters as follows:

```
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @Params = N'@MusNo bigint, @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date';

exec sp_executesql @Sql, @Params, @MusNo = @MusNo, @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

Even better is the following which will completely avoid any sql injection.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @Params = N'@IslemKodu varchar(30), @MusNo bigint, @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date';

SET @Sql = N'SELECT [KartNo],[HesapNo],[TCKN],[CepTel],[MusNo],[Alacakli],[Tutar],[Tarih],[AtmNo],[Borclu]
    FROM [ATMDB].[isb].[NakitIslemSorgu] WITH (NOLOCK)       
    WHERE MusNo = @MusNo  and cast([Tarih] as Date)>= @StartDate and cast([Tarih] as Date) <= @EndDate and CashResult = 0
    and IslemKodu = ISNULL(@IslemKodu, IslemKodu) ORDER BY Tarih DESC'

exec sp_executesql @Sql, @Params, @IslemKodu = @IslemKodu, @MusNo = @MusNo, @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

Comment: But with your "even better" version - once you've reached that point, why bother with `sp_executesql` at all, since it's now a static string, and so could just be literal code within the current SP?

Comment: That's a case of not seeing the forest for the tress :-) Well spotted.

Comment: I actually don't know how to thank you :-). The wrriten statement shown below is the solution for my problem. Thank you so much.
IslemKodu = ISNULL(@IslemKodu, IslemKodu)